# Django 2 distinct model field items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to get a list of distinct items in a field of a module and then display all the items associated with that field.

For example, in a school administration system there is a school module and a student model. Each student has a color associated with them as a 'color' field. I want to create a page where the page lists all the distinct colors in the school and then under each color a list of students that belong to that color.

Would I write this function in views?

Here is what I have so far in views.py:

```
class SchoolColorDetailView(DetailView):
    model=models.School
    template_name='school_app/school_color_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['colors']=Student.objects.all().order_by('color').distinct('color')
```

This will get me a list of all colors (but not by school). Is there any way to only get the colors by school and then all the students associated with that color? Do I have to create a dictionary for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:

Here are the models:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("school_app:school_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students', on_delete="Protect")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("school_app:student_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Second update:

I am trying to make a template that looks something like this (not sure the best way to do that):

```
{% for color in colors %}
 <ul>
   <li>{{color}}
     {% for student in color %}
     <ul>
       <li>{{student}}</li>
     </ul>
     {% endfor %}
   </li>
 </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: Added models to post

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
context['colors']=Student.objects.all(
       ).order_by('color').distinct('color')
```

to

```
context['colors']=self.student_set.all(
       ).order_by('color').distinct('color')
```

Comment: I get this error when I run the code:
SchoolColorDetailView object has no attribute "student_set'

Do I have to set this attribute somewhere?

Comment: oops, my fault  Can you give me some of the template that you're trying to render, and I'll fix up my code to match that.

Comment: I added the template that I am trying to render to the bottom of my question. Thanks for your help!